# If then statement in model builder for several features after a clip

Tags: modelbuilder

[image]I'm merging several databases and clipping out certain areas of interest.  Sometimes there are no points that are clipped because there is nothing in the clip.  I have each of the features output to a geodatabase.  Is there a way for it not to export the feature class to the geodatabase if the file is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the result of the [Get Count (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) tool, and check it within [Using If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_If_Then_Else_logic_for_branching/002w00000022000000/) logic to check for features.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write code on this.  I'm trying to do it with calculate values for the next step.  I don't know how to plug in an if-then going from Row Count > Calculate Values.  I'm fairly new to model builder.  I'm going from "Select" > "Copy Features", but I want it to stop going if there's nothing in the feature.

Comment: @joebob, pg 110 of Getting to Know ArcGIS ModelBuilder goes over how to use if-elif statements.